# Integral of $\int \frac{\sin(x)}{3\cos^3(x)+\sin^2(x)\cdot\cos(x)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So, from here $$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{3\cos^3(x)+\sin^2(x)\cdot\cos(x)} dx$$
I divided by cos(x) and I got
$$\int \frac{\tan(x)}{2\cos^2(x)+1} dx$$
But I'm stuck here.
I tried to substitute $t=\cos(x)$

$$\int \frac{-1}{t\cdot(2t^2+1)} dt$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try $s=t^2$. (And please add $dx$ at the three places where it belongs.)

Comment: That is, after the substitution $t=\cos(x)$ that was mentioned in a previous version of the post.

Comment: I am inclined to think that the solution I posted below is probably the most straightforward one unless you have one that uses some surprising "trick".

Answer (score 5):

Alternate solution

$$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{3\cos^3(x)+\sin^2(x)\cos(x)} dx=\int \frac{\tan(x)}{2\cos^2(x)+1} dx= \int \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} \frac{\tan(x)}{2+\sec^2(x)} dx$$

Thus, after $t= \tan(x)$ you get

$$\int  \frac{t dt}{t^2+3} $$

Comment: I didn't think to divide for $$cos^2(x)$$ and put $$sec^2(x) = 1+tan^2(x)$$ Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 4):

From the last integral, use $\frac{1}{t(2t^2+1)}=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{2t}{2t^2+1}$. Now, you have:
$$\int \frac{1}{t\cdot(2t^2+1)} \, \mathrm{d}t=\int \frac{1}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t-\int \frac{2t}{2t^2+1} \, \mathrm{d}t=\ln|t|-\frac{1}{2}\ln|2t^2+1|+C$$

Comment: Thank you! You reach that point by usinf partial fraction, am I right?

Comment: @HelloEveryone: Yes, I did.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int \frac{\sin(x)}{3\cos^3(x)+\sin^2(x)\cdot\cos(x)}\,dx = \int \frac{1}{3\cos^3(x)+\sin^2(x)\cdot\cos(x)}\,\Big(\sin x \,dx\Big)
$$
$$
= \int \frac{1}{3\cos^3(x)+(1-\cos^2 x)\cdot\cos(x)}\,\Big(\sin x \,dx\Big) = \int \frac{1}{3u^3 + (1-u^2)u}\,(-du)
$$
Then use partial fractions.

**Later edit in response to comments:**
$$
\int \frac{1}{3u^3 + (1-u^2)u}\,(-du) = \int\frac{-du}{u(2u^2 + 1)}
 = \int \frac{A}{u} + \frac{Bu+C}{2u^2+1} \, du
$$
Two logarithms plus an arctangent.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use partial fractions at that point.

Comment: @Gigili : Fortunately you're mistaken; it's quite simple.  I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Done.  It's two logarithms plus an arctangent.

Comment: Well, now that you simplified it ...

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{\sin x}{3 \cos ^{3} x+\sin ^{2} x \cos x} d x \\
=& \int \frac{\sin x d x}{\cos x\left(3 \cos ^{2} x+\sin ^{2} x\right)} \\
=& \int \frac{d(\cos x)}{\cos x\left(2 \cos ^{2} x+1\right)} \\
=& \int\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}-\frac{2 \cos x}{2 \cos ^{2} x+1}\right) d(\cos x) \\
=& \ln (\cos x)-\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d\left(2\cos ^{2} x+1\right)}{2 \cos ^{2} x+1} \\
=& \ln |\cos x|-\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(2 \cos ^{2} x+1\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$